# SQL Query to select a specific part of the values in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table in a database and one of the columns of the table is of the format `AAA-BBBBBBB-CCCCCCC`(in the table below column **Id**) where A, B and C are all numbers (0-9). I want to write a `SELECT` query such that for this column I only want the values in the format `BBBBBBB-CCCCCCC`. I am new to SQL so not sure how to do this. I tried using `SPLIT_PART` on `-` but not sure how to join the second and third parts.

Table -

| Id | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123-4567890-1234567 | First Name | 199 |
| 456-7890123-4567890 | Hulkamania | 200 |

So when the query is written the output should be like

Output

```
4567890-1234567
7890123-4567890
```

Comment: Which version of SQL you use. STRING_SPLIT is available from 2016

Comment: Assuming MS SQL Server `select right(id, len(id) - charindex('-', id)) from your_table;`

Comment: It is a bad idea to store the combined number when you are actually interested in its parts. That even violates database normalization. If the separate parts of the ID have separate meanings, then store them in separate columns.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Did you try to look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-06062705-1EC8-44ED-89B8-0F0573B74EA2)? If you've tried `split_part` then you should have `invalid identifier`, and should not care about "how to join the second and third parts"

Comment: @programerAnel SQL is not synonymous with SQL Server and the question mentions SPLIT_PART (and not STRING_SPLIT).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the request comments, you should not store a combined number, when you are interested in its parts. Store the parts in separate columns instead.

However, as the format is fixed 'AAA-BBBBBBB-CCCCCCC', it is very easy to get the substring you are interested in. Just take the string from the fifth position on:

```
 select substr(col, 5) from mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the right part of a column starting at the 4th character

```sql
SELECT RIGHT(Id, LEN(Id)-4) AS TrimmedId;
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Oracle, Postgres, MySQL, SQLite, because `len` doesn't exist there.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `regexp_substr`

```
with x ( c1,c2,c3 ) as 
(
select '123-4567890-1234567', 'First Name' , 199 from dual union all
select '456-7890123-4567890', 'Hulkamania' , 200 from dual 
)
select regexp_substr(c1,'[^-]+',1,2)||'-'||regexp_substr(c1,'[^-]+',1,3) as result from x ;
```

**Demo**

```
SQL> with x ( c1,c2,c3 ) as
(
select '123-4567890-1234567', 'First Name' , 199 from dual union all
select '456-7890123-4567890', 'Hulkamania' , 200 from dual
)
select regexp_substr(c1,'[^-]+',1,2)||'-'||regexp_substr(c1,'[^-]+',1,3) as result from x ;  2    3    4    5    6

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4567890-1234567
7890123-4567890

SQL>
```